# Java XML parsing DOM performance

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb, xmlbeans

I'm part of a team creating a data store that passes information around in large XML documents (herein called messages). On the back end, the messages get shredded apart and stored in accumulo in pieces. When a caller requests data, the pieces get reassembled into a message tailored for the caller. The schemas are somewhat complicated so we couldn't use JAXB out of the box. The team (this is a few years ago) assumed that DOM wasn't performant. We're now buried in layer after layer of half-broken parsing code that will take months to finish, will break the second someone changes the schema, and is making me want to jam a soldering iron into my eyeball. As far as I can tell, if we switch to using the DOM method a lot of this fart code can be cut and the code base will be more resilient to future changes. My team lead is telling me that there's a performance hit in using the DOM, but I can't find any data that validates that assumption that isn't from 2006 or earlier.

Is parsing large XML documents via DOM still sufficiently slow to warrant all the pain that XMLBeans is causing us?

**edit 1** In response to some of your comments:

1) This is a government project so I can't get rid of the XML part (as much as I really want to).

2) The issue with JAXB, as I understand it, had to do with the substitution groups present in our schemas. Also, maybe I should restate the issue with JAXB being one of the ratio of effort/return in using it.

3) What I'm looking for is some kind of recent data supporting/disproving the contention that using XMLBeans is worth the pain we're going through writing a bazillion lines of brittle binding code because it gives us an edge in terms of performance. Something like [Joox](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOX) looks so much easier to deal with, and I'm pretty sure we can still validate the result after the server has reassembled a shredded message before sending it back to the caller.

*So does anyone out there in SO land know of any data germane to this issue that's no more than five years old?*

Comment: The problem with DOM is not performance, but memory footprint. DOM parses entire XML into memory, so a huge XML document will cause out-of-memory. For performance, Unless you're already at the threshold of performance through-put, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Until measured - there cannot be arguments for or against any solution. Moreover measurements should be compared to the whole system. Optimizations 100mks -> 80mks in a component, when total handling takes 10-100ms is useless.

Comment: @Andreas memory is pretty cheap these days so I'm not so much worried about that. Do you happen to have any data supporting your claim? I want to believe but I need solid numbers if I'm going to win the fight over dumping our current crap-tacular parsing code in favor of something more sensible.

Comment: It'll be rather difficult to say since we've no idea how you're parsing the XML right now.

Comment: shouldn't matter how I'm parsing it now. my question is a general one: is using something like XMLBeans significantly more performant that parsing XML the DOM way?

Comment: I'd try something event/stream-based like StAX as basis for parsing big messages. DOM isn't inperformant per se, you just probably not need the whole tree.

Comment: Strange - I've seen some rather unwieldy XML schemas being handled by JAXB, so I wonder whether that "couldn't use JAXB" is really a blocker. -- How large is "large"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the best technology for heavy duty XML processing, you might want to investigate [this paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20170808171656/http://sdiwc.net/digital-library/web-admin/upload-pdf/00000582.pdf). The best technology will no doubt be clear after you read it...

The paper details :

```
Processing XML with Java – A Performance Benchmark
Bruno Oliveira1 ,Vasco Santos1  and Orlando Belo2 1 CIICESI,
School of Management and Technology,
Polytechnic of Porto Felgueiras, PORTUGAL
2 Algoritmi R&D Centre, University of Minho
4710-057 Braga, PORTUGAL
```

Comment: w00t - this helps a lot, t/y!

Comment: The link is dead. Please always use snippets from there and add the link as a reference, otherwise this thread is a waste of time for the rest of the people because external links are always broken.

Answer (score 2):

Data binding solutions like XMLBeans can perform very well, but in my experience they can become quite unmanageable if the schema is complex or changes frequently.

If you're considering DOM, then don't use DOM, but one of the other tree-based XML models such as JDOM2 or XOM. They are much better designed.

Better still (but it's probably too radical a step given where you are starting) don't process your XML data in Java at all, but use an XRX architecture where you use XML-based technologies end-to-end: XProc, XForms, XQuery, XSLT.

I think from your description that you need to focus on cleaning up your application architecture rather than on performance. Once you've cleaned it up, performance investigation and tuning will be vastly easier.